# how do i sort results from php query

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, search

What statement would I use to sort results generated from this php script. I want to sort 
- 1st Category, - 2nd Brand, - 3rd Price.

I have looked around for example but nothing seems to apply to the script Im using. Any help is appreciated.

```
<?php
$query = $_GET['query']; 
// gets value sent over search form

$min_length = 3;
// you can set minimum length of the query if you want

if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ // if query length is more or equal minimum length then

    $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
    // changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;

    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
    // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection

    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM plfwinvtable
        WHERE (`Brand` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`Description` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`Category` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());

    // * means that it selects all fields, you can also write: `id`, `title`, `text`
    // articles is the name of our table

    // '%$query%' is what we're looking for, % means anything, for example if $query is Hello
    // it will match "hello", "Hello man", "gogohello", if you want exact match use `title`='$query'
    // or if you want to match just full word so "gogohello" is out use '% $query %' ...OR ... '$query %' ... OR ... '% $query'

    if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

        while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
        // $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into array, while it's valid it does the loop

            echo "<span style='font-size:14px'>".$results['Category']."</span> - <strong>".$results['Brand']."</strong> - ".$results['Description']." - <span style='color:red;'>$".$results['Price']."</span> ".$results['Size']."<br>";
            // posts results gotten from database(title and text) you can also show id ($results['id'])
        }

    }
    else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
        echo "No results";
    }

}
else{ // if query length is less than minimum
    echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `mysql_*` functions. They're deprecated and will be removed from PHP. Instead you can use `PDO`.

To sort results you should use `ORDER` keyword at the end of your query, eg.

```
ORDER BY Category, Brand, Price
```

Comment: Not quite sure where to add this? you say at the end of the query. Are you referring to $raw_results

Comment: I'm talking about string that you are passing to `mysql_query`. You should add it there.

Comment: Thank you for help, that worked. As far as mysql being depreciated, I have several scripts that use this. Should I change mysql_ statement to mysqli_ or pdo_ as you suggested, or has the functions changed in format as well

Comment: `mysqli_*` is similar in use to `mysql_*` but `PDO` is a lot different so you have to read some about it first.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `ORDER` on the SQL statement will order your results

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM plfwinvtable
    WHERE (`Brand` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`Description` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`Category` LIKE '%".$query."%') ORDER BY Category, Brand, Price") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thank you Idealcastle. I figured that out, after looking at the statement. Your contribution makes this clear for other novices who read this post.